# Best enterprise VPN providers

Tags: security, vpn

Our company requires enterprise VPN solution for secure access of network from outside. Which are the Best enterprise SSL  VPN providers ? Our company is based in US and India.

Comment: What kind of VPN. Site To Site for US and India? Client Access? SSL VPN for "Clientless" connection? IPsec? PPTP?
What Firewall Product are you currently using?

Comment: SSL vpn. We are using iptables firewall

Answer (score 1):

We used F5 Networks- Firepass SSL VPN in our corporate environment. It is easy to manage and integrate well with Active Directory.

The performance is acceptable even for a slow client connection from APAC region to the controller in Europe.

Comment: even Cisco PIX is moving towards SSL VPN nowadays. Free alternative for SSL VPN, try openVPN first.

Answer (score 0):

My VPN knowledge isn't so great but couldn't your company buy, for example, a Netgear VPN/Firewall router and run the connection through there?

Answer (score 0):

We use a Juniper VPN and it works flawlessly with AD. It also provides a webex-like remote meeting functionality but without needing to pay for a separate license, or per-meeting charges.

Answer (score 0):

I find Cisco ASA devices quite enjoyable. Once you get the hang of the ASDM (Java control interface) it's a breeze to configure.